# find: How to force a non-zero exit status

Tags: linux, find

I have glossed over the man page for find and `-quit` seems to partly do what I want, except it will only cause `find` to return non-zero if an error has occurred.  So how can `find` be forced to return non-zero or at least be spoofed into returning non-zero in a way that is readable to maintainers?  So far I have this example:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -exec echo {} \; -o \( -printf "FAIL\n" -a -quit \) \)
./scooby
./shaggy
./velma
./daphne
./fred
$ echo $?
0
```

But if I replace the echo with a call to false, I get the desired early exit, but no non-zero exit code:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -exec false {} \; -o \( -printf "FAIL\n" -a -quit \) \)
FAIL
$ echo $?
0
```

Update:

I am trying to get find to return non-zero when `-exec` returns false, i.e. the command that executed returned non-zero.  Currently, `find` just converts the non-zero `-exec` call into a boolean state to be used as part of a `find` expression.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -exec chmod a+x {} \; -o \( -printf "FAIL\n" -a -quit \) \)
```

This currently will never return non-zero if the chmod fails.  I want to be able to return non-zero if the chmod fails, as well as exit early, which it already does using `-quit`.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve (by returning a non-zero exit code)?

Comment: So is the objective to exit early when `chmod` fails or is there more to it?

Comment: Exit early (`-quit`) but also exit with a non-zero exit code.  I was hoping `find` had some kind of `-exit 1` implementation, but can't see anything that stands out.

Answer (score 4):

If you always want to return a non-zero exit code, use `&& false` as shown below:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f ...  && false
```

---

Use `grep` to look for the the special `FAIL` string printed by `find`. It will return zero if the `exec` failed, non-zero otherwise.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -exec chmod a+x {} \; -o \( -printf "FAIL\n" -a -quit \) \) | grep -q "FAIL"
```

Comment: I don't `always` want to exit non-zero, just under certain conditions.

Comment: You can use `grep` to look for the `FAIL` string.

Comment: That was in the pipeline, but it's not as clean.  It also requires `set -o pipefail` in order for it to work with `set -e`

Answer (score 3):

`find` has the "plus" version of the `-exec` command. These actually exit with non-zero status, if one or more invocations of the command fail. So:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec false "{}" "+"
```

will give you the desired "fail" exit status. But it will execute your command (here `false`) only once, with all files found listed as arguments. So you need to use a command, that can handle a list of files, and that will exit a non-zero status, if processing any of the provided files failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good idea to abuse the exit code of `find` to state a result.  It will prevent `find`'s standard way of reporting errors (e. g. I/O errors, permission denied errors, etc.).

I think you really should use some kind of output of `find` to state the result and check for that.

```
rm ./findResult 2>/dev/null
find /path/to/my/dir -name '*my*pattern*' -fprintf ./findResult "fail" -quit
result=$(cat ./findResult 2>/dev/null || echo "success")
```

This way you have a general way of returning values (not just 8 bit int but arbitrary strings).  Using the exit code, on the other hand, will even cloak errors detected by `find`.